# Chart.js:9352 Failed to create chart. Unable to dynamically create charts

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ngfor

Hi I'm coming up to this error when trying to dynamically create some charts in my angular project.

> Chart.js:9352 Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the
>   given item

```
export class StudentStudyProgressComponent implements OnInit {
  charts = [];
  semesters = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  constructor(private logic: LogicService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.makeDetailCharts(this.semesters);
  }

  private makeDetailCharts(semesters: number[]) {
  semesters.forEach((semester)=>{

   this.charts.push(
    new Chart('chartStudyProgress' + semester, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: ['Geslaagd', 'Opgenomen', 'Resterend'],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: this.logic.giveStudyProgressForSemester(this.student.Curriculum, semester),
            borderColor: "#3cba9f",
            backgroundColor: [
              ('#66B266'),
              ('#FFFF66'),
              ('#FF7F7F')
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Semester '+semester
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
      }
    })
   );
  });
 }
}
```

I think the problem occurs when I want to dynamically create the charts in my html:

```
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let semester of semesters">
  <div class="col-4">
   <div [hidden]="!charts">
    <canvas id="{{'chartStudyProgress'+semester}}" style="max-width: 30%;">{{ charts[semester] }}</canvas>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

If I declare the charts statically it works:

```
<div class="row" >
 <div class="col-4">
  <div [hidden]="!charts">
   <canvas id="chartStudyProgress1" style="max-width: 30%;">{{ charts[1] }}</canvas>
   <canvas id="chartStudyProgress2" style="max-width: 30%;">{{ charts[2] }}</canvas>
   <canvas id="chartStudyProgress3" style="max-width: 30%;">{{ charts[3] }}</canvas>
   <canvas id="chartStudyProgress4" style="max-width: 30%;">{{ charts[4] }}</canvas>
   <canvas id="chartStudyProgress5" style="max-width: 30%;">{{ charts[5] }}</canvas>
   <canvas id="chartStudyProgress6" style="max-width: 30%;">{{ charts[6] }}</canvas>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is there an expert who can help me create my charts dynamically?

Comment: Arrays start at 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to get canvases before they are created in the view. Use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.makeDetailCharts(this.semesters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Angular so I didn't know of the existence of ngAfterViewInit()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I think that is not how you should declarate the charts. Instead I would call it like this:

```
<canvas
        id="{{'chartStudyProgress'+semester}}"
        [data]="chartData"
        [labels]="chartLabels"
        [chartType]="chartType"
        [legend]="chartLegend"
        [colors]="chartColors"
        [options]="chartOptions">
</canvas>
```

Then, I would declarate those variables in the ts file.
For example:

```
this.chartData = this.logic.giveStudyProgressForSemester(this.student.Curriculum, semester); 
this.chartType = 'doughnut';
this.chartColors = [
            {
                backgroundColor: [('#66B266'), ('#FFFF66'), ('#FF7F7F')],
                borderColor: "#3cba9f"
            }
        ];
this.chartOptions = {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Semester '+semester
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
}
```

Let me know if it was useful. Good luck!

Comment: All I had to do was use ngAfterViewInit instead of ngOnInit. That solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

My resolve in Angular 12:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById(id);
if (!ctx) return;
```

and In html:

```html
<canvas id="{{id}}"></canvas>
```